# Unable to get bluebird promise and mongoose's save() to work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

Can anyone help me figure out how to rewrite the following working code in promise? I want to execute an insert query and then send the data back to clients via socket.js

```
  var func = require("functions")
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var mongo_models = require('./database/mongo_model')(mongoose);
  var Promise = require("bluebird");

  socket.on("submit",function(d){ 
   if(d[0].src !== undefined)
   {
      var data = func.clear(sanitizer,d),
      tab = new mongo_models.Tab({avg:0,post:data});
      tab.save(function(err,tw){
        io.sockets.in('index').emit("update",tw)
      })
   }
  });
```

I have tried the following code but I'm getting `undefined` from `console.log(b)`. Apparently the `save()` isn't returning any result.
Promise:

```
  socket.on("submit",function(d){ 
   if(d[0].src !== undefined)
   {
    Promise.props({
       one: func.clear(sanitizer,d)
    }).then(function(a){

       return new mongo_models.Tab({avg:0,post:a.one}).save();

    }).then(function(b){

       console.log(b); // undefined
       io.sockets.in('index').emit("update",b) 

    }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
    })
   }
  });
```

Comment: Is `.save()` supposed to return a promise for something? Is it documented by mongoose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save is problematic in Mongoose as being an exception to the rule of promise returning functions there.

I highly recommend that you promisify mongoose using bluebird which exposes a `saveAsync` function:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var func = require("functions")
var mongoose = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
var mongo_models = require('./database/mongo_model')(mongoose);
```

And then return the async call as:

```
   //                                            Note the suffix
   return new mongo_models.Tab({avg:0,post:a.one}).saveAsync();
```