# Building an array in a loop using Mongoose FindOne & Bluebird Promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I'm using Node, Mongoose and Bluebird and am working on a site that serves up several RSS feeds.

When a feed is retrieved I want to pull any articles that I've already saved to my table from the table and combine them with any new articles in the feed into an array.I cannot seem to find a way to wait for the promises to all resolve before returning my array. The basic problem is that when `loadRSSFeed` is called it essentially immediately calls the return `articleList` line.How do I line all of this up so nothing is returned until my promises are all resolved?

This first function just sort of wraps everything:

```
function loadRSSFeed(rss, newsSource) {
var articleList = [];

// Promise.each(rss.channel[0].item, function (article) {
rss.channel[0].item.forEach(function (article) {
    var item = {};
    item.link = tryEval(article, "article.link[0]");

    Promise(function() {
        return getArticle(newsSource, article, item, articleList)
        .then(function() {
             return articleList; 
        })
    })
})                 
};
```

The getArticle function looks like this:

```
function getArticle(newsSource, article, item, articleList) {
return Articles.findOne({ link: article.link }, function (err, doc) {
    if (doc) {
        articleList.push(doc._doc);
    }
    else {
        item.title = tryEval(article, "article.title[0]");
        item.pubDate = tryEval(article, "article.pubDate[0]");
        item.sourceId = newsSource.id;
        item.sourceName = newsSource.name;

        if (item.pubDate) {
            try {
                item.pubDate = new Date(item.pubDate);
            }
            catch (err) {
                item.pubDate = "";
            }
        };

        item.contentSnippet = tryEval(article, "article.description[0]");
        if (item.contentSnippet.indexOf("<") > 0) {
            item.contentSnippet = item.contentSnippet.substring(0, item.contentSnippet.indexOf("<") - 1);
        };

        item.image = tryEval(article, "article['media:content'][0].$.url|article.thumbnail[0]");
        if (!item.image) {
            item.image = photoHunt(item);
            if (item.image) {
                item.contentSnippet = "";
            }
        };
        if (item.title && item.link && (item.image || item.contentSnippet)) {
            articleList.push(saveArticle(item));
        }
    }
})
}
```

and the saveArticle function looks like this:

```
function saveArticle(article) {
var curArticle = {};

if (article._id) {
    curArticle = article;
    curArticle._id = article._id;
    curArticle.isNew = false;
}
else {
    curArticle = new Articles();
    curArticle.title = article.title;
    curArticle.link = article.link;
    curArticle.pubDate = article.pubDate;
    curArticle.image = article.image;
    curArticle.contentSnippet = article.contentSnippet;
    curArticle.sourceName = article.name;
    curArticle.sourceId = article.sourceId;

    if (article.haters) {
        curArticle.haters = article.haters;
    };

    if (article.lovers) {
        curArticle.lovers = article.lovers;
    };

    if (article.readers) {
        curArticle.readers = article.readers;
    };
}
curArticle.save(function (err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
});
return curArticle;
};
```

This is what the Articles model looks like, just in case there's an issue here:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose'), 
Schema       = mongoose.Schema;
// NewsSchema = new Schema({ name: String });   

var ArticlesSchema   = new Schema({
title: String,
link: String,
pubDate: Date,
image: String,
contentSnippet: String,
sourceName: String,
lovers: [],
haters: [],
readers: [],
forumLinks: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Articles', ArticlesSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you can just use Bluebird's `Promise.map()` to both iterate through all the RSS feeds and to wait for all of them to finish:

```
function loadRSSFeed(rss, newsSource) {
    // Promise.each(rss.channel[0].item, function (article) {
    return Promise.map(rss.channel[0].item, function(article) {
        var item = {};
        item.link = tryEval(article, "article.link[0]");
        return getArticle(newsSource, article, item, articleList);
    }).then(function(articleList) {
        // filter out any empty items
        return articleList.filter(function(article) {
            return !!article;
        });
    });
}


function getArticle(newsSource, article, item) {
    var find = Promise.promisify(Articles.findOne, {context: Articles});
    return find({link: article.link}).then(doc) {
        if (doc) {
            return doc._doc;
        } else {
            item.title = tryEval(article, "article.title[0]");
            item.pubDate = tryEval(article, "article.pubDate[0]");
            item.sourceId = newsSource.id;
            item.sourceName = newsSource.name;
            if (item.pubDate) {
                try {
                    item.pubDate = new Date(item.pubDate);
                } catch (err) {
                    item.pubDate = "";
                }
            };
            item.contentSnippet = tryEval(article, "article.description[0]");
            if (item.contentSnippet.indexOf("<") > 0) {
                item.contentSnippet = item.contentSnippet.substring(0, item.contentSnippet.indexOf("<") - 1);
            };
            item.image = tryEval(article, "article['media:content'][0].$.url|article.thumbnail[0]");
            if (!item.image) {
                item.image = photoHunt(item);
                if (item.image) {
                    item.contentSnippet = "";
                }
            };
            if (item.title && item.link && (item.image || item.contentSnippet)) {
                return saveArticle(item);
            }
        }
        // unsure what your code intends if there was no article here
        // this will return undefined which will get filtered out later
    })
}

function saveArticle(article) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var curArticle;
        if (article._id) {
            curArticle = article;
            curArticle._id = article._id;           // don't know why this is needed since curArticle === article already
            curArticle.isNew = false;
        } else {
            curArticle = new Articles();
            curArticle.title = article.title;
            curArticle.link = article.link;
            curArticle.pubDate = article.pubDate;
            curArticle.image = article.image;
            curArticle.contentSnippet = article.contentSnippet;
            curArticle.sourceName = article.name;
            curArticle.sourceId = article.sourceId;
            if (article.haters) {
                curArticle.haters = article.haters;
            };
            if (article.lovers) {
                curArticle.lovers = article.lovers;
            };
            if (article.readers) {
                curArticle.readers = article.readers;
            };
        }
        curArticle.save(function (err) {
            if (err) reject(err) else resolve(curArticle);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Super close, if I am seeing this correctly, articleList is coming back in the calling function as what appears to be the unresolved promise and new articles are no longer be saved - I think because the promise is left in limbo.

Comment: @MikeFeltman - I missed the part about `saveArticle()` being async (I didn't see that).  Do you need me to help with that too or can you apply these same principles to that function?

Comment: Let me give it a shot and if not, I'll be back. :) Thanks again! I'm not sure that's the only issue though because some of the articles are already in the table and they aren't in the array either. Maybe not, I guess there can't really be an array until all the promises are resolved.

Comment: @MikeFeltman - I redid my answer to incorporate `saveArticle()`.

Comment: Thanks pretty close to what I had. I'm getting an error when the promisified find is called. It's an unhandled rejection TypeError: Invalid select() argument. Must be string or object, at Query.select. I traced it and it's in the Mongoose internals. It appears to be an issue with not specifying a projection, which is supposed to be optional.

Comment: @MikeFeltman - What version of Bluebird are you using?  Promisify has a different argument structure for 2.x vs. 3.x.

Comment: "bluebird": "^3.0.5",

Comment: @MikeFeltman - OK, then I've updated the `.promisify()` call for `.findOne()` in `getArticle()` for Bluebird 3.x (they changed the interface from 2.x to 3.x).  See if that helps.

Comment: @MikeFeltman - FYI, it is probably easier to promisify Mongoose at a higher level than done here (I just worked with the code you posted) like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294515/unable-to-get-bluebird-promise-and-mongooses-save-to-work-in-node-js

Comment: Yeah, you had actually already posted the 3.x syntax previously and I was already using that. I tried the older syntax as well just to be sure.

Comment: You can safely use arrows in node, and `Promise.coroutine`. I recommend promisifying at a higher level but you already suggest that so that's good. `promisify` is slow to call at runtime and not initialization time, for single usage prefer `fromNode` (although I doubt it'd dominate performance here).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - What is `fromNode`?  When trying to offer answers involving dynamically created database objects/methods from a database that I don't know, I'm often not sure how to best promisify the dynamically created objects, so I tend to recommend something safe (and in this case, the OP is still have issues with it).  I haven't personally moved my brain over to arrows yet.

Comment: Sorry, `fromNode` was renamed `fromCallback`, my bad :)

Comment: @MikeFeltman - I updated `getArticle()` to use `Promise.fromCallback()` which is better for single use promisification.  Still best to promisify mongoose at a higher level if possible.

Comment: Ok, I had to do some minor refactoring, but this is all working except for one caveat. The actual call to loadRSS doesn't wait for the promises to resolve. Execution continues on with the next line. Eventually when all of the promises are resolved articleList is populated.

Comment: @MikeFeltman - `loadRSSFeed()` returns a promise.  So you use it like this: `loadRSSFeed(...).then(function(articles) { code here });`

Comment: Ok, first of all, you are the man! Stupid rookie mistake on my part on the last issue. I was just dealing with the article list in the then() function when the promise finished. I obviously needed to move all the code that happens after that into the then. So I have this working and going to accept the answer and owe you a beer or 20. Should I post the final code in an additional answer? (I will still work on promisifying all of Mongoose in the future on this.)